# C# Moq call base implementation

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, moq

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, but I have a very simple setup, however, I cannot get my test to return the value from the implementation.

**Test Class**

```
public class Tests : ApiTestBase
{
    private TestController controller;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        controller = new TestController(MoqAppServices.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ShouldReturn_UserName_IfUserExists()
    {
        var userName = controller.GetUser();
        userName.Should().Be("Hello");
    }
}
```

**Api Test Base**

```
public class ApiTestBase
{
    protected readonly Mock<IAppServices> MoqAppServices;

    protected ApiTestBase()
    {
        // Setup Moq Services
        MoqAppServices = new Mock<IAppServices>();
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface IAppServices
{
    string GetAllUsers();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class AppServices : IAppServices
{
    public AppServices()
    {
        
    }

    public string GetAllUsers()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

**Test Controller**

```
public class TestController
{
    private readonly IAppServices _appServices;

    public TestController(IAppServices appServices)
    {
        _appServices = appServices;
    }

    public string GetUser()
    {
        var userToReturn = _appServices.GetAllUsers();
        return userToReturn;
    }
}
```

However, it just consistently returns null, if I add `MoqAppServices.Setup(x => x.GetAllUsers()).Returns("Hello World");` then it returns `Hello World` but I want it to return the method return value, what am I missing?

Comment: Why are you mocking `IAppServices`? Create a new instance of it and call the method, and you shall get the result.

Comment: @FortyTwo I am mocking `IAppServices` because my `TestController` takes the interface in the constructor and I'm trying to test the flow through `TestController`

Comment: Then don't expect to get the return of AppServices. You should get your defined response from the IAppServices Mock. Remember its called "Unit"test for a reason. You should just test one Unit.

Comment: If you mock `AppServices` you will get the value you looking for. If you are mocking `IAppServices` then you need to set up what the method should return.

Comment: Looks like you missed out any actual concrete testing. You've created a test controller to test a mock of appservices. What are you actually trying to test?

Comment: If you're trying to test the whole flow, that's normally an integration test and doesn't involve mocking out anything. If you have a database/datastore connected then there's debate about whether that should write the test data and then clean it up after or use an in memory implementation or something. Various tools like Postman can run suites of integration tests for apis.

Comment: @sr28 I was trying trying to test a full flow of from `TestController` all the way through to `AppRepository` (not in this question, took it out to simply my question). What I was expecting to happen is I would create `TestController` with a Moq of `IAppServices` which I could then use to call the base implementation in `AppServices` - in this case I am not testing much, just trying to figure out why my test isn't calling the base implementation of `GetAllUsers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever it is you're trying to do - you're doing it wrong.

Your `Mock<IAppServices>` knows nothing about the implementation in `AppServices` because it knows nothing about `AppServices`.

If `AppServices` is the system you're trying to test, then you should never mock it. Just call the method you want to test with appropriate parameters and Assert the results.

If `AppServices` is a dependency, then you should never call the actual implementation - that misses the entire point of mocking something, you want to disconnect yourself from the implementation and provide a mocked method that will simply do exactly what is expected of it by the system under test.

But if you neeed it you could use Moq in this way:

```
var appServices = new AppServices():
var appServicesMock = new Mock<IAppServices>();

appServicesMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetAllUsers())
    .Callback(() => appServices .GetAllUsers());
```

When you call your `appServicesMock.GetAllUsers` after that MOQ will  redirect the call to the actual instance of `AppServices`.

Note that such a test would be called an [integration test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests) because in this case you are actually testing how the modules interact with each other. And in this case you can use actual instance instead of mocks:

```
public void Setup()
{
    var appServices = new AppServices():
    controller = new TestController(appServices);
}
```